# What is this antiderivative? Does the limited domain of sec(x) affect my answer?

Tags: integration

Here are the equations I need to find the antiderivative of. Am I missing something?:

$$ h(\theta) = 2 \sin{\theta} - \sec^2{\theta}$$
Is it:
$$ -2\cos{\theta} - tan{\theta}$$

and this one:

$$r({\theta}) = \sec{\theta} \cdot \tan{\theta} - 2e^{\theta}$$
Is $$  \sec({\theta}) - 2e^{\theta}$$ the antiderivate ?

These are my professors' comments which I cannot understand:

> Note that $\sec(x)$ has a limited domain which you must take into account here – so your final answer is the same as you have, with the constant depending on $n$, i.e. $C_n$, and on the interval ($n\pi - \pi/2, n\pi + \pi/2$). ($-2$)

Comment: Yes, the second antiderivate is correct and has the same domain (all $\theta$ with $\cos(\theta)\ne 0$). Substituting $x=\cos(\theta)$ should help.

Comment: What about my professor's comments?

Comment: The professor expected that you restrict the function on an interval where it does not have a singularity. Within such an interval, the integral can be taken without issues. And apparently, the professor also expected the "obligatory" integration constant (here depending on the interval chosen). "Minus two points" is a hard decision.